# No se me descargan los branch de un repositorio

Tags: git, github

Estoy tratando de descargar un repositorio para usar un branch en especifico. El inconveniente es que cuando lo clono solo se me descarga el branch "Master", cuando en realidad hay 3 branch.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo el comando "git branch" para ver todos, pero como dije anteriormente, solo el master me aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

`git fetch origin <nombre_de_tu_branch>`

o simplemente haciendo un

`git fetch --all`

Eso deberia de hacer un update de todos los remote branches.

Comment: No pude usando esos comandos